# why is display:block css only staying open momentarily

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I have a Rails app with profile pages that allow users to post different types of information about themselves.

On the left side of the page, there is, for example, a link that says "Add Job," which when clicked displays a form (originally hidden through css `display:none;`) which lets the user add details about a job they've had. This link is in the 'span2' column in the html below. If the user already has entered the details of a job in the database, that information will appear in the middle 'span6' column and then, if the user wants to add details of another job he had, the job form will open in the 'span3' column on the right. However, if there are no jobs in the db, the job form will appear in the middle because there's no content pushing it to the right.

The site uses Backbone to change the css from `display: none` to `display: block`, like this.

```
 "click .addjob": "showJobForm"

  showJobForm: function(){
       $('.jobform').css('display', 'block');
    },
```

Problem: When I click on the link 'add a job,' the form is flashing on the page and then disappearing.

There are three factors that affect this behavior:

1. The form is more likely to stay open if there is  already an
   entry in the database (i.e. the middle column is containing
   something)
2. The form is more likely to stay open if there is no '#' at the
   end of the url, which gets placed there (this is a Backbone thing)
   when I click the 'add a job.' For example, if I click to add a job,
   the form might open and stay open, but then if I don't refresh the
   url (to clear away the #) the next time I want to add a job. I
   included this code in my Backbone code (which doesn't use a router)
   to try to get rid of the # but it's not working

   ```
        if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
           Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});
       }
   ```
3. This is a Rails 4 app. I previously built the same app in Rails 3
   and, despite the presence of the above 2 factors, I never had this
   issue in the Rails 3 app. There has been some changes to Javascript
   in Rails 4.

Question: Can you explain why display:block might not be working for me as it did earlier (in my Rails 3 app), or tell me how to debug this.

**the Markup**

```
<div class="row employment">
    <div class="span2">
      <h5>Employment</h5>
   <a href="#" class="addjob">add</a>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
       <table class="table table-striped">


                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <!-- <th> Category</th> -->
                  <!--     <th>Practice Areas</th> -->
                      <th>Company</th>
               <th>Title</th>
                <th>Start</th>
                 <th>End Date</th>
                 <th>Current Position</th>

                    </tr>
                  </thead>
 <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Esso </td>
       <td>gas pumper </td>
        <td>1966 </td>
         <td>1968 </td>

          <td>true </td>
      <td></td>
       <td><a class="editarea 2" href="/lawyer_profiles/22?job_id=2">edit</a></td>
      <td><a data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" href="/employments/2" rel="nofollow">destroy</a></td>
    </tr>




</tbody>


  </table>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">

 <div class="jobform">
 <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/employments" class="simple_form form-inline" id="new_employment" method="post" novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="faiGo6e1//1IkifVBfGHfd7lksBg+ZDUfjuRK05xs7M="></div>
  <div class="control-group string optional employment_employer"><label class="string optional control-label" for="employment_employer">company</label><div class="controls"><input class="string optional company" id="employment_employer" name="employment[employer]" type="text"></div></div>
   <div class="control-group string optional employment_jobtitle"><label class="string optional control-label" for="employment_jobtitle">job title</label><div class="controls"><input class="string optional job-title" id="employment_jobtitle" name="employment[jobtitle]" type="text"></div></div>
<div class="control-group select optional employment_startwhen"><label class="select optional control-label" for="employment_startwhen">Startwhen</label><div class="controls"><select class="select optional" id="employment_startwhen" name="employment[startwhen]"><option value=""></option>
..
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option></select></div></div>
                             <!--  order: [:month, :year] %> -->
  <div class="control-group select optional employment_endwhen"><label class="select optional control-label" for="employment_endwhen">Endwhen</label><div class="controls"><select class="select optional" id="employment_endwhen" name="employment[endwhen]"><option value=""></option>
...
<option value="2009">2009</option>
<option value="2010">2010</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2013">2013</option></select></div></div>
  <div class="control-group boolean optional employment_currentposition"><label class="boolean optional control-label" for="employment_currentposition">current position?</label><div class="controls"><input name="employment[currentposition]" type="hidden" value="0"><label class="checkbox"><input class="boolean optional currentposition" id="employment_currentposition" name="employment[currentposition]" type="checkbox" value="1"></label></div></div>

  <input class="btn" input_html="{:class=&gt;&quot;special&quot;}" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Employment">
   <a class="btn btn-inverse" href="/lawyer_profiles/22">Hide form</a>
 <!-- <a href="#" class="hideawardform">hide</a> -->
</form>
</div>


    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replace "display: block"

 on

```
showJobForm: function(){
       $('.jobform').show();
    },
```

Comment: The same thing is happening when I try it this way.

Comment: Not sure could it help, but try to remove `{reset: true}` from any backbone actions. Probably after event on `@showJobForm` backbone View rerenders the View.